# how to convert the for-loop in a permutation function to a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation

My question is how to convert the for-loop in the posted code to a recursive function. I have look at some loops' conversion, and it is kinda hard to convert a loop in recursion functions.

I am learning c++, and I know that there is a way to convert the for-loop to recursion function. There is a permutation function in an online article that involves a for-loop. I want to make the function completely recursive, but I have no idea how to start with.

```
void RecPermute(string soFar, string rest)
{
 if (rest.empty()) {
     cout << soFar << endl;
 } else {
     for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
         string remaining = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i+1);
         RecPermute(soFar + rest[i], remaining);
     }
 }
```

here is the link of the article:https://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspacs106b/H19-RecBacktrackExamples.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert loops to recursions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103514/how-do-i-convert-loops-to-recursions)

Comment: I believe there is no an easy way because in a certain way it's already a recursion

Comment: @ayun12 I agree. This is not simple.

Comment: @ayun12: it's not "in a certain way", it *is* already recursive.  OP is trying to make it two-level recursion.